# SwiftyJSON won't parse my dictionary

Tags: swifty-json

I have a simple array of categories coming from server. Each category is a dictionary.

```
 var json = JSON(json!)

 println(json)
 for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
    println(subJson)
```

The subjs. printout is:

```
{
"thumbnailImage" : null,
"isNew" : true,
"id" : 30,
"name" : "Abilities",
"mainImage" : null
}
```

So shouldn't :

```
 if let extId = subJson["id"].string{
       NSLog(subJson["id"].string!)
 }
```

Run and log "30"? It never passes the conditional.

What am I obviously doing wrong?

Comment: It was a number, I was casting it to string, it worked with: subjs.["id].number

Answer (score 1):

It was a number, I was casting it to string, it worked with:

```
subjs.["id].number
```